# How to fill div with values from form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form with such structure:

```
...
<select name="Employee"> 
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
</select> 

<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="Yes" unchecked>Include Email Contact
<input type="checkbox" name="phone" value="Yes" unchecked>Include Phone Contact
Job Title: <input type="Text" name="jobTitle" size="20"><br> 
<input type="Button" value="Generate" onclick="show()" id="refresh"> 
...
```

And a div:

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="ft_name"></div>
    <div class="ft_pos"></div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_meta">E-Mail:</div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_data"></div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_meta">Phone:</div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_data"></div>
</div>
```

How can I show my values in div section by pressing the button without reloading the entire page?
I know Javascript a bit, but unfortunately, didn't find the answer yet. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote what you tried so far!

Comment: So if I understand right, you have a form and on submit you wish to show it in div as text. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution, using unobtrusive vanilla javascript.

The function `showData()` runs when the `button` is clicked.

Then, the function `showData()`:

- gets the Boolean value of each checkbox (either `true` if checked or `false` if unchecked)
- rewrites the Boolean value as a string (a value of `true` becomes `'Yes'` and a value of `false` becomes `'No'`)
- rewrites the relevant data field, including the string.

```js
function showData() {

    var emailValue = document.querySelector('input[value="email"]').checked;
    var phoneValue = document.querySelector('input[value="phone"]').checked;

    var data = document.getElementsByClassName('data')[0];
    var dataFields = data.getElementsByTagName('div');

    if (emailValue === true) {emailValue = 'Yes';} else {emailValue = 'No';}
    if (phoneValue === true) {phoneValue = 'Yes';} else {phoneValue = 'No';}

    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {

        switch (i) {
            case (0) : dataFields[i].textContent = 'E-Mail: ' + emailValue; break;
            case (1) : dataFields[i].textContent = 'Phone: ' + phoneValue; break;
        }
    }
}

var button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
button.addEventListener('click',showData,false);
```

```css
form, .data, label, input[type="button"] {
display: block;
}

form, .data {
float: left;
width: 200px;
}

input[type="button"] {
margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="email" unchecked>Include Email Contact</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="phone" unchecked>Include Phone Contact</label>
<input type="Button" value="Generate">
</form>

<div class="data">
<div class="ft_tbl_meta">E-Mail:</div>
<div class="ft_tbl_meta">Phone:</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get elements of class by calling document.getElementsByClassName(class_name)
Example javascript code below

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ft_name");
    x[0].innerHTML = form.name.value;   
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("ft_tbl_meta");
    x[0].innerHTML = form.email.value;     // name email is one provided in form
    // Do same for all other classes
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter something in the box: <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="Yes" unchecked>Include 
Email Contact
<input type="checkbox" name="phone" value="Yes" unchecked>Include Phone Contact
Job Title: <input type="Text" name="jobTitle" size="20"><br> 
<input type="Button" value="Generate" onclick="show(this.form)" id="refresh"> 
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: How is this getting the values from the form?

Comment: Pass this.form to function, and use the form variable inside function to access the fields.
For detailed example check http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077176/scripting-jvm-languages/using-javascript-and-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

set some IDs for your divs you wish to take/assign values from/to and put this code

> IncludeEmailCheckBox is for your "include Email" checkbox
>
> EmailToDiv is for your div to get the email
>
> EmailFromDiv is for your input for Email
>
> IncludePhoneCheckBox is for your "include Phone" checkbox
>
> PhoneToDiv is for your div to get the Phone
>
> PhoneFromDiv is for your input for Phone

```
function show(){
if (document.getElementById("IncludeEmailCheckBox").checked){
   document.getElementById("EmailToDiv").innerHTML =    document.getElementById("EmailFromDiv").innerHTML ;}
if (document.getElementById("IncludePhoneCheckBox").checked){
   document.getElementById("PhoneToDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("PhoneFromDiv").innerHTML ;}
return false;
}
```

Remember to change IDs as nessesary

Answer (score 0):

here is your view (I updated) using Jquery:

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="ft_name"></div>
    <div class="ft_pos"></div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_meta">E-Mail:<span id="email_here"></span></div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_data"></div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_meta">Phone:<span id="phone_here"></span></div>
    <div class="ft_tbl_data"></div>
</div>
```

Now fetching and printing values:

```
var Employee = $( "select[name=Employee]" ).val();
$('.ft_name').html(Employee);
var email = $( "input[name=email]" ).val();
$('#email_here').html(email);
var phone = $( "input[name=phone]" ).val();
$('#phone_here').html(phone);
var jobTitle = $( "input[name=jobTitle]" ).val();
$('.ft_pos').html(jobTitle);
```